# How to recode a byte variable to a string variable in Stata

Tags: string, byte, stata, recode

I'm trying to recode a byte variable in my Stata file to a string variable. But it is showing me an error (stating that it doesn't recognize the element). Stringing  it isn't working either. Can I do this in Stata?

The data file I have includes the demographic information of continents. I recoded it based on life expectancy (`lexp`). The code I'm using is:

```
recode lexp (min/72 =1) (73/75 = 2) (76/max=3)
```

Now I need to recode `3` to a string value `A`.

Using `recode lexp (3=A)`

I get

> unknown el A in rule

Comment: Could you give us a code sample to see what you did better ?

Answer (score 2):

`recode` is meant to change the values of numeric variables to other numeric values; not to strings.

I think you want to `label` your values:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
byte bytevar
1
2
3
end

// add value labels
label define lblbyte 1 "A" 2 "B" 3 "C"
label values bytevar lblbyte

// list
list

// but they are really numeric values
list, nolabel
```

See `help label`.

You can also define the value labels directly within the `recode` command. Read `help recode` carefully.

Comment: Thanks! The labelling worked! Can we recode a byte variable to a string variable?

Comment: The `recode` command is not meant to do that. You can convert a numeric value to its corresponding string using the `string()` function. What is the purpose of converting the numeric value `3` into the string `A`? Is labeling not enough for your task?